# Slim framework rest api update from v2 to v3

Tags: rest, api, slim, php-5.5

hi i'm new to slim framework and it's basics and I have found many examples of rest apis based on v2 (http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/)I really like the code partition and methods of v2  but I could not update to v3 
can anyone help me with this

```
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
    $app = new \Slim\Slim();

    // ID utilisateur - variable globale
    $user_id = NULL;

    /**
     * Ajout de Couche intermédiaire pour authentifier chaque demande
     * Vérifier si la demande a clé API valide dans l'en-tête "Authorization"
     */
    function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
        // Obtenir les en-têtes de requêtes
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        $response = array();
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

        // Vérification de l'en-tête d'autorisation
        if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // Obtenir la clé d'api
            $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
            // Valider la clé API
            if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
                //  Clé API n'est pas présente dans la table des utilisateurs
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "Accès Refusé. Clé API invalide";
                echoRespnse(401, $response);
                $app->stop();
            } else {
                global $user_id;
                // Obtenir l'ID utilisateur (clé primaire)
                $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
            }
        } else {
            // Clé API est absente dans la en-tête
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Clé API est manquante";
            echoRespnse(400, $response);
            $app->stop();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ----------- MÉTHODES sans authentification---------------------------------
     */
    /**
     * Enregistrement de l'utilisateur
     * url - /register
     * methode - POST
     * params - name, email, password
     */
    $app->post('/register', function() use ($app) {
                // vérifier les paramètres requises
                verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'email', 'password'));

                $response = array();

                // lecture des params de post
                $name = $app->request->post('name');
                $email = $app->request->post('email');
                $password = $app->request->post('password');

                // valider adresse email
                validateEmail($email);

                $db = new DbHandler();
                $res = $db->createUser($name, $email, $password);

                if ($res == USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY) {
                    $response["error"] = false;
                    $response["message"] = "Vous êtes inscrit avec succès";
                } else if ($res == USER_CREATE_FAILED) {
                    $response["error"] = true;
                    $response["message"] = "Oops! Une erreur est survenue lors de l'inscription";
                } else if ($res == USER_ALREADY_EXISTED) {
                    $response["error"] = true;
                    $response["message"] = "Désolé, cet E-mail éxiste déja";
                }
                // echo de la repense  JSON
                echoRespnse(201, $response);
            });

function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields) {
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = "";
    $request_params = array();
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;
    // Manipulation paramsde la demande PUT
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
    }
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }

    if ($error) {
        //Champ (s) requis sont manquants ou vides
        // echo erreur JSON et d'arrêter l'application
        $response = array();
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Champ(s) requis ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' est (sont) manquant(s) ou vide(s)';
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}

/**
 * Validation adresse e-mail
 */
function validateEmail($email) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Adresse e-mail n'est pas valide";
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}

/**
 * Faisant écho à la réponse JSON au client
 * @param String $status_code  Code de réponse HTTP
 * @param Int $response response Json
 */
function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    // Code de réponse HTTP
    $app->status($status_code);

    // la mise en réponse type de contenu en JSON
    $app->contentType('application/json');

    echo utf8_encode(json_encode($response));
    }
$app->run();
```

Comment: Read the upgrade guide from slim2 to slim3: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html

Comment: the problem is i didin't understand how to transform the verifyRequiredParams() and validateEmail() functions so i can stop the app if there is an error

Comment: "Slim Core has removed Stop/Halt. In your applications, you should transition to using the withStatus() and withBody() methods." so you can return a bad request like this: ``return $request->withStatus(400);`` when you do this inside the route it is basically the same.

Comment: i know that the problem is they removed also  \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

Comment: so i just want to know how to replace it or pass another params in middleware  so i can use these functions when ever i want

Comment: Well the structure has changed, you need to change you code to make it work again. Stackoverflow is no coding service so you need to try it by yourself, when you have problems with that, we'll help you, but you need to show us what you've tried.

Comment: i know that it's not a coding service , all i ask for is an idea to change this code function stucture ,

Answer (score 0):

well after deep search i changed the code to be like this

```
require '../libs/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App(  [
        'settings' => [
            'addContentLengthHeader' => false

        ]
    ]);

$verifyRequiredParams = function ($request, $response, $next) {

    $route = $request->getAttribute('route');
    $validators = $route->getArgument('validators');
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = "";
    $request_params = array();
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;
    // Manipulation paramsde la demande PUT
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {

        parse_str($request->getBody(), $request_params);
    }
    foreach ($validators as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }

    if ($error) {
        //Champ (s) requis sont manquants ou vides
        // echo erreur JSON et d'arrêter l'application

        $resp=array();
        $resp['error']=true;
        $resp["message"] = 'Champ(s) requis ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' est (sont) manquant(s) ou vide(s)';
        $response= $response->withJson($resp, 400);

    }else{    $response = $next($request, $response);}

    return $response;
};
$authenticate=function($request, $response, $next) {
    // Obtenir les en-têtes de requêtes
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $resp = array();


    // Vérification de l'en-tête d'autorisation
    if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // Obtenir la clé d'api
        $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
        // Valider la clé API
        if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
            //  Clé API n'est pas présente dans la table des utilisateurs
            $resp["error"] = true;
            $resp["message"] = "Accès Refusé. Clé API invalide";
            $response=$response->withJson($resp, 401);
        } else {
            global $user_id;
            // Obtenir l'ID utilisateur (clé primaire)
            $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
            $response=$response = $next($request, $response);
        }
    } else {
        // Clé API est absente dans la en-tête
        $resp["error"] = true;
        $resp["message"] = "Clé API est manquante";
        $response=$response->withJson($resp, 400);
    }
    return$response;
};
$app->post('/task', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $resp = array();
    $task = $request->getParsedBody()['task'];

    global $user_id;
    $db = new DbHandler();

    //Création d'une nouvelle tâche
    $task_id = $db->createTask($user_id, $task);

    if ($task_id != NULL) {
        $resp["error"] = false;
        $resp["message"] = "Tâche créé avec succès";
        $resp["task_id"] = $task_id;
        $response=$response->withJson($resp, 201);
    } else {
        $resp["error"] = true;
        $resp["message"] = "Impossible de créer la tâche. S'il vous plaît essayer à nouveau";
        $response=$response->withJson($resp, 200);
    }



    return $response;
})->setArguments(['validators' => ['task']])->add($verifyRequiredParams)->add($authenticate);

$app->run();
```

Comment: currently you are the love of my life...;)